# Error on loading an existing project in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

When trying to load an existing project on Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 I get the following error

> The following error has occurred during XML parsing:
>
> File: C:\pathTo.vcproj
> Line: 49501
> Column: 6
> Error Message:
> System error: -2147154682

The line where it fails is on a moc file that doesn't exists because as a moc file it will get generated during the build. The weird thing is that there are several moc files in other projects but not all of them fail to load only certain ones.

Comment: I would just remove the offending line so the load will work and then add them back from the GUI.  I will say it seems odd that a file that is generated is part of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Anon Mail's comment, I figured out what was needed. 
I am not providing a full explanation of the answer because I don't fully understand the black magic behind it but here's what I did to fix my problem:

1. Make a copy of the incriminated .vcproj file :)
2. Manually change the .vcproj file and remove all the files (in my case all the mocs) that fails to load as Anon Mail suggested.
3. The project should then be loaded correctly
4. Once loaded close Visual Studio and restore the previous .vcproj file
5. Open up your solution and it should be fine.

Again, I don't really understand why it works this way but I hope this may help someone else in the future.